# Nature of Aghora-Panth Yogis

Tags: yogi

The late Mohanlal Agrawal had written two volumes entitled, "Aghor Nagara Vage". In these two volumes, he recounts his extraordinary and surreal encounters with the authentic yogis and sages of northern India as well as Nepal.  Various phenomena defying the conventional laws of physics and nature are detailed.  Throughout the book, he makes references to the Aghora-Panth sadhus and yogis.  They believe in a form of strict non-dualism and are sometimes regarded as "sinister" and "heretical" by the conventional Hindu population.  Academic scholars have described the Aghora-Panth as unorthodox and antinomian.  Where in the Grand Tree of Hinduism does this Aghora-Panth exist? Is it an obscure branch of Shaivism?